# How to format a Date in Java ME?

Tags: java, java-me

So I have a Date object and I want to create a method so that it prints the Date in the following format:

```
11 September 2011, 9:15pm
```

How do I do that?
As of now I am just doing a toString to the date and it gives me all the GMT information and seconds precision that I don't need. Do I have to use a DateFormatter or is there an easier way to do this?

***This was edited to include Java ME in the title and the tags after some of the answers that were correct for the original question were posted.***

Comment: You could have just Googled it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `SimpleDateFormat` class to format your date.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

I guess the pattern would be something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, h:ma");
format.format(yourDate);
```

EDIT for Java ME;
I read that there is no SimpleDateFormat class in Java ME specs. So I would try Calendar;

First put your date to the Calendar, then get all you need. Better is make this a method

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date myDate = new Date(); // as an example, date of "now"
calendar.setTime(myDate);

int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int monthNumber = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

String[] _months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
String[] months = new String[12];
for(int i =0; i < 12; i++){
    months[i] = _months[i];
}
//because there is something wrong, we have a 12. month in the name of "" (nothing)

//or if there is no DateFormatSymbols class in your plans
//you may write for yourself;
/*
String[] monthNames = {"January", "February",
            "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
            "August", "September", "October", "November",
            "December"};
*/
String month = months[monthNumber]; //or String month = monthNames[monthNumber];

int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String amPm = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==1 ? "am" : "pm";
System.out.println(day + " " + month + " " + 
    year + ", " + hour + ":" + minute + amPm);
```

Comment: I believe they dont have the SImpleDateFormat in the JavaME library

Comment: I guess not, and what about Calendar class? Can you use it on J2ME? If you can, then you may make your own formatter method by using Calendar methods.

Comment: @YasinOkumus there is [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Calendar.html) in J2ME MIDP. Also I think that your suggestion to make _own formatter_ is the way to go in Java ME (or maybe there are 3rd party libs that do that already)

Comment: @gnat; I mean just this format shouldn't be so difficult with Calendar; "11 September 2011, 9:15pm" (if we can use all Calendar specs on JavaME)

Comment: yes we have calendar in JavaME, so how would you do that with a Calendar? A calendar takes in a Date, but can't produce a string to format it nicely