# How to format a non plain date in Java?

Tags: java, regex, java-7

I have two dates as following that need to format them but I am receiving following exception. My main issue is with the `th rd etc` in the day part. I could not find any answer for this question. I checked all these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364443/how-to-format-a-date-in-java-me),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java),[3](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/),[4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java/6987802#6987802) I think I should use Regex but not sure how.

```
 10th Dec 2019 -> 2019-12-10 
 10th December 2019 -> 2019-12-10
```

**Code**

```
 String date1 = "10th Dec 2019";
 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM YYYY").parse(date1);
 System.err.println(date);
 String date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(date);
 System.err.println(date2);
```

**Exception**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10th Dec 2019"
```

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or Java 7?

Comment: This already has an answer. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6987802/1737819

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am using 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace all the expected undesired sufiixes by an empty string, and then parse:

```
    String s = "10th Dec 2019";

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d = fmt.parse(s.replaceFirst("th|nd|st|rd", ""));
    System.out.println("d = " + d);
```

Comment: How about if I use Regex?

Comment: My answer does use a regex. replaceFirst() takes a regex and replaces the first the matching substring by the second argument.

Comment: How about parsing date **10st August 2019** ?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the quantifier first, then parse the date as usual.

Something like this would work:

```
String[] input = {     "10th Dec 2019",
                       "10th December 2019",
                       "1st December 2019",
                       "3rd December 2019"
                 };

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
DateFormat result = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
for(String s : input) {
    s = s.replaceAll("^(\\d+).{2}", "$1");  //The .{2} will match any two characters, which should be the th, st, nd and rd.
    System.out.println(result.format(df.parse(s)));
}
```

Yields:

```
10-12-2019
10-12-2019
01-12-2019
03-12-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape explicit literals in date formats by putting them in single quotes within the pattern like that:

`Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th' MMMM YYYY").parse(date1);`.

However, that solution does not support wildcards, which I assume you'd need for "st" and "nd" suffixes. So I suggest you do some preprocessing of the input based on a regex to drop the "st/nd/th" suffix.

Answer (score 0):

For your String you can use:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th' MMMM YYYY").parse(date1);
```

Comment: The issue is with 1st, 12th etc

Comment: @Jack `12th` is not an issueand 1st is not requested in your question. you should add it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7, it's concidered best practice to use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for handling dates. So I recommend you look into it. The api is way easier to use then [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). (Parsing too)

When you later migrate to Java 8, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (JSR-310) package is based on `Joda Time`, so you will have an easy time migrating.

Comment: Actually, java.time is inspired by Joda-Time but not based on it. Concepts are largely the same but your code may differ significantly. Best to start with java.time if on Java 8 or later.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to show some example code to more directly address the Question?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
String suffix = getSuffix(inputDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" d'" + suffix + "' MMMM yyyy");
return dateFormat.format(currentCalDate.getTime());

// getSuffix
private String getSuffix(int inputDay) {
    if (day >= 11 && day <= 13) {
        return "th";
    }
    switch (day % 10) {
        case 1:
            return "st";
        case 2:
            return "nd";
        case 3:
            return "rd";
        default:
            return "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: The suffix can just be replaced instead of adding the suffix in the DateFormat. That's easier and cleaner for this problem.